# Javascript Timers assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some issues trying to use the console to modify the time remaining on one site.

I want to be able to set the Time remaining to zero to be able to proceed to the next page.

I believe that the issue is that there are multiple things that need to be set in order to proceed to the next page.

See code below, any help you can provide would be appreciated.

```js
var pageLoaded = 0; 
var timerStatus = 'pending';
var secondsRemaining = -1;
var secondsElapsed = -1;
var startTicks = 0;
var errorCount = 0;
var estimatedSecondsRemaining = -1;
var zeroTimeCounter = 0;
var intervalIdUpdateBothTimers;
var nonLinearGuid = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('AutoSave()', 120000);
    intervalIdUpdateBothTimers = setInterval('UpdateBothTimers()', 1000);

    if (timerStatus == 'pending') {
    
        var totaltimeclock = document.getElementById('TotalTimeClock');
        if (totaltimeclock != null) {
            document.getElementById('TotalTimeClock').innerHTML = '-- \: -- \: --';
        }

        var timeremainingclock = document.getElementById('TimeRemainingClock');
        if (timeremainingclock != null) {
            document.getElementById('TimeRemainingClock').innerHTML = '-- \: -- \: --';
        }

        StartTimer();
    }

});

function loaded(i,f) {
 if (document.getElementById && document.getElementById(i) != null) 
 {
     f(); 
 }
 else if (!pageLoaded) setTimeout('loaded(\''+i+'\','+f+')',100);
}

function SuspendTimer() {
    UpdateBothTimers();
    
    if (timerStatus == 'active') {
        var data = "s=2&cp=" + this.location.pathname + "&nlg=" + GetNonLinearGuid();
        timerStatus = 'suspended';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Courses/ajax/CourseData.aspx",
            data: data,
            success: displayTime,
            async: false
        });

        clearInterval(intervalIdUpdateBothTimers);
    }
    
}

function AutoSave()
{
    if (timerStatus == 'active')
    {
        SaveTime();
    }
}

function SaveTime()
{
    var data = '';
    if (typeof window.IsScormPage === 'undefined')
    {
        data = "cp=" + this.location.pathname + "&sp=false";
    }
    else
    {
        data = "cp=" + this.location.pathname + "&sp=true";
    }

    data += "&nlg=" + GetNonLinearGuid();

    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Courses/ajax/CourseData.aspx",
  data: data,
  success: displayTime,
  async: false
 });  
}

function StartTimer()
{
    timerStatus = 'active';

    SetNonLinearGuid();
    SaveTime();
}

// Sets the nonLinearGuid with the one in the DOM
// the GUID was generated in the server side and
// passed it to the client side (DOM)
function SetNonLinearGuid()
{
    var $nonLinearGuid = $("#nonLinearGuid");

    if ($nonLinearGuid === undefined)
    {
        $nonLinearGuid = $("input[name=nonLinearGuid]");
    }

    if ($nonLinearGuid.length)
    {
        nonLinearGuid = $nonLinearGuid.val() || null;
        window.nonLinearGuid = window.nonLinearGuid || nonLinearGuid;
    }
}

function GetNonLinearGuid() {
    var nlg = (window.NonLinearGuid || nonLinearGuid),
        admin = getQueryStringByName("admin", parent.window.location.href) || "";

    if (admin.toLowerCase() == "d3v") {
        printNonLinearGuid(nlg);
    }

    return nlg;
}

function getQueryStringByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

function displayTime(result)
{
    
 if (result.isOk == false)
 {
  alert(result.message);
 }
 else
 { 
     var d = new Date();
        startTicks = d.getTime();
     
  secondsRemaining = parseInt($(result).find("SecondsRemaining").text());
  secondsElapsed = parseInt($(result).find("SecondsElapsed").text());
  redirectUrl = $(result).find("RedirectUrl").text();

        var suspendTimer = $(result).find("SuspendTimer").text();
        var dataNonLinearGuid = "?nlg=" + GetNonLinearGuid();
  
  if (redirectUrl != "") {
      location.href = redirectUrl;
  }
  
     isError = $(result).find("Error").text();
     
     if (isError == "true")
     {
         errorCount++;
         
         if (errorCount > 3)
         {
             logout();
         }
     }

     isOverworked = $(result).find("IsOverworked").text();
     if (isOverworked == "true") 
     {
            location.href = "/Courses/MyAccountNonLinear.aspx" + dataNonLinearGuid;
     }

     if (suspendTimer.length > 0) {
         if ($.trim(suspendTimer).toLowerCase() == "true") {
             SuspendTimer();
         }
     }       
 }
}

function logout()
{
    window.top.location.href = "/Courses/loggedout.aspx";
}

function UpdateBothTimers() {
    
    if (timerStatus != 'active') return;
    
    if (secondsElapsed >= 0)
    {    
        UpdateElapsedTimer();
        //secondsElapsed++;
    }

    if (secondsRemaining >= 0) {
        UpdateRemainingTimer();
    }

    if (estimatedSecondsRemaining <= 0 && zeroTimeCounter == 0) {
        zeroTimeCounter++;     
        SaveTime();
    }
}
var lang;
function qt(m,lng) {
    
    $('#timeRemaining').css('display', 'none');
    setTimeout("$('#EOMQuiz').submit();", m * 1000);
    lang = lng;
    setTimeout('updateQ('+ m +')', 1000);
}

function updateQ(m) {
   
    --m;
    var text;
    if (lang == 'es') {
        text = 'Entregar - ' + m + ' segundos restantes para completar la prueba';
    }
    else {
        text = 'Submit - ' + m + ' seconds remaining to complete the quiz';
    }
   
    if (m > 0) {
       
        setTimeout('updateQ('+m+')', 990);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#eomsubmitDiv').css('background-color', '#FF0000');
       text ='Submitting... Please Wait.';    
    }
   
    if (m <= 10 && m > 0)
    {
        if (m % 2 == 0)
        {
            $('#eomsubmitDiv').css('background-color', '#FFFF00');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#eomsubmitDiv').css('background-color', '#FFFFAA');        
        }
           
    }
    
    $('#eomsubmit').attr('value', text);
}

function UpdateElapsedTimer()
{
    var s = secondsElapsed + (GetTickDiff()/1000);  
    UpdateTimer('TotalTimeClock', s, 'UP');
}

function GetTickDiff()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var tickDiff = d.getTime() - startTicks;
    return tickDiff;
}

function UpdateRemainingTimer()
{
    
    var s = secondsRemaining - (GetTickDiff()/1000);

    estimatedSecondsRemaining = s;
    
    if (s < 0) s = 0;
    
    UpdateTimer('TimeRemainingClock', s, 'DOWN');
}

function UpdateTimer(ClockID,ElapsedSeconds,ClockDirection){

    
 //check to see if we can run this code yet
 if(document.getElementById && document.getElementById(ClockID) != null){

  //declare vars
  var _Seconds = 0;
  var _Minutes = 0;
  var _Hours = 0;
  
  //Format Seconds
  _Seconds = Math.floor(ElapsedSeconds % 60);
  if(_Seconds <= 9) {
   _Seconds = "0"+_Seconds;
  }
  
  //Format minutes
  _Minutes = Math.floor(ElapsedSeconds/60 % 60);
  if(_Minutes <= 9) {
   _Minutes = "0"+_Minutes;
  }
  
  //Format hours
  _Hours = Math.floor(ElapsedSeconds/3600 % 60);
  if(_Hours <= 9){
   _Hours = "0"+_Hours;
  }
  
  document.getElementById(ClockID).innerHTML = _Hours + ":" + _Minutes + ":" + _Seconds;
  
        if (timerStatus != 'active')
        {   
            setTimeout('UpdateTimer(\''+ClockID+'\','+ElapsedSeconds+',\''+ClockDirection+'\')',1000); 
            return;
        }

  if(ElapsedSeconds > 0 || ClockDirection == "UP"){
  
   if(ClockDirection == "UP")
   {
    ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedSeconds + 1;
   }
   else
   {
    ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedSeconds - 1;
   }
   
   //setTimeout('UpdateTimer(\''+ClockID+'\','+ElapsedSeconds+',\''+ClockDirection+'\')',1000);   
  }
  else{
   //Timer has hit zero. Lets make sure the next buttons are visible.
   $('#next_top').show();
   $('#next_bot').show();
  } 
 }
 else if(!pageLoaded) //call function again in 100ms
 {
  //setTimeout('UpdateTimer(\''+ClockID+'\','+ElapsedSeconds+',\''+ClockDirection+'\')',100);
 }
} 

function DisplayNextButtons(){
 $('#next_top').show();
 $('#next_bot').show();
}

function hideNextButtons(){
 $('#next_top').hide();
 $('#next_bot').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *I believe that the issue is that there are multiple things that need to be set in order to proceed to the next page.* What are those things? Are you getting any errors? What is the exact problem you are seeing? Your question (and the accompanying code) is too vague.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Code wont work without any HTML. Edit was an unneeded bump.

Comment: @FrankerZ Code was already in a snippet. I just made some corrections to it. And, having it in a snippet is useful as a starting point for potential answers.

Comment: So I am trying to basically use the Chrome console on this website to cheat the timer that is counting down to zero.

Comment: In the console I enter "TimeRemainingClock=0" and it sets it to zero. however when I Try to proceed it is not allowing me to continue. I also enter "UpdateRemainingTimer=0;" but that doesnt work either

Comment: Please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I happened to stumble upon the same code. If you were on the same site as me,
I have a potential fix.
Instead of editing the time remaining I setup a script that will click next when the time has expired. I was too lazy to check whether they are checking timestamps server side. Also the server logs will look more similar to a regular user.

Instructions:

1. Download the following extension for Chrome
   [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en](https://web.archive.org/web/20210412200415/https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en)
2. Navigate to the site
3. click the CJS chrome extension button
4. check "enable cjs for this host"
5. paste the following JS snippet into the JS box

   ```
   var t=setInterval(try_hit_next,1000);

   function try_hit_next(){
       if (estimatedSecondsRemaining <= 0)
           window.location = $('#next_top').parent()[0]['href'];
   }
   ```
6. click save

Answer (score 0):

1) No needs to assign *"setInterval"* to a variable *t*

2) Has somebody tried to make **fully automated** script for this resource, i mean "driving defensive course" cause it pushes popups with personal questions randomly and besides shows pages with a сourse-related questions (constantly the same), so hope it's gonna be very useful "tool" )

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and rephrase what you are trying to say, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the timers are actually being kept server-side.  You can watch a POST to CourseData.aspx and it will return with new values for SecondsRemaining and SecondsElapsed.  These new values are used to **set** the client-side timers.  You can change the client side variables all you want but when you move to the next page, another call to CourseData.aspx is done to fetch the server time.  So the server's timers rule this entire process.

I believe the only reason you see any JS timers is to provide a (now hidden) simple "time remaining" clock for the user.

However I am willing to bet that there's a way to POST a new time or SecondsRemaining to the CourseData.aspx page, I just don't know what set of post data variables might be needed to do so.